# Hello, how can I make that date list with Riverpod when the entire list is selected when no date is selected?

Tags: flutter, datetime, riverpod

I want to bring a list according to two selected date ranges. My codes are as follows. When I select a date, the whole list appears again. I use riverpod as Sate management to track my dates when selecting two dates. How can I solve this problem?
My ChanceNotifier is like this

```
class TimeNotifier1 extends ChangeNotifier {
 DateTime endDate = DateTime(0);
 DateTime startDate = DateTime(0);
 void chanceQuery1(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
   startDate = t1;
   endDate = t2;
   notifyListeners();
 }
}

final timeProvider1 = ChangeNotifierProvider<TimeNotifier1>((ref) {
 return TimeNotifier1();
});
```

this my service methods codes

```
  Future<List<pompa.Pomvardimas>?> getAll({required WidgetRef ref,DateTime? startDate,
    DateTime? endDate,
  }) async {
    String _query = NetworkRoutes.POMVARDIMAS.rawValue;
    endDate = ref.watch(timeProvider1).endDate;
    startDate = ref.watch(timeProvider1).startDate;
   // query = ref.watch(queryProvider).query;
    if (endDate == DateTime(0) || startDate == DateTime(0)) {
      endDate = null;
      startDate = null;
    }
_query = endDate != null && startDate != null
          ? "${NetworkRoutes.GETTWOBETWEENTIMEPOMPA.rawValue}?t1=$startDate&t2=$endDate"
          : NetworkRoutes.POMVARDIMAS.rawValue;
    
    final response =
        await manager.send<pompa.ResponsesModels, pompa.ResponsesModels>(_query,
            parseModel: pompa.ResponsesModels(), method: RequestType.GET);
    
    
    debugPrint("responseeeeeeeeeeee${response}");
    if (response != Null) {
      if (pomvardimas.isEmpty) {
        if (response.data?.data is List) {
          pomvardimas = response.data!.data!;}}}
```

my view page code like this

````
class ViewPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ViewPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _ViewPageState();
}

class _ViewPageState extends ConsumerState with BaseViewModel {
  int? id;
  DateTime? startDate1;
  DateTime? endDate1;

 GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState1 = GlobalKey();
  IPomvardimasService? _pomvardimasService;
  List<Pomvardimas>? _pomvardima;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
     _pomvardimasService = PomvardimasService(VexanaManager.instance.networkManager, scaffoldState1);
    
    startDate1 = DateTime(0);
    endDate1 = DateTime(0);
    debugPrint("baslangıc ${startDate.toString()}");
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    this.getPompa();
  }

  Future getPompa({DateTime? t1, DateTime? t2}) async {
    t1 = startDate1;
    t2 = endDate1;
    _pomvardimasService = PomvardimasService(
        VexanaManager.instance.networkManager, scaffoldState);
    _pomvardima = await _pomvardimasService!
        .getAll(ref: ref, endDate: t2!, startDate: t1!);
    setState(() {});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int indexx = ref.watch(showHello);
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (indexx != null) {
      setState(() {
        var user = ref.watch(userrProvider);
        var id = user.id;
      
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const DrawerPage(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(90.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                indexx == 0
                    ? const HomeInput()
                    : const SizedBox(),
                
                indexx == 2
                    ? Container(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 50,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                        child: TextButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                backgroundColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)),
                            onPressed: () {
                              showCustomDateRangePicker(
                                context,
                                dismissible: true,
                                minimumDate: DateTime.now()
                                    .subtract(const Duration(days: 360)),
                                maximumDate: DateTime.now()
                                    .add(const Duration(days: 360)),
                                endDate: endDate1,
                                startDate: startDate1,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                primaryColor: Colors.black,
                                onApplyClick: (start, end) {
                                setState(() {
                                    endDate1 = end;
                                    startDate1 = start;
                                    ref
                                        .read(timeProvider1.notifier)
                                        .chanceQuery1(end, start);

                                    getPompa(t1: start, t2: end);
                                     endDate1 = null;
                                    startDate1 = null;
                                  });
                                },
                                onCancelClick: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    endDate1 = null;
                                    startDate1 = null;
                                  });
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            child: Text("Tarih Aralığı Seciniz")),
                      )
                    : SizedBox()
              ],
            )),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          " App",
          style: context.textTheme.headlineSmall?.copyWith(
            color: context.colors.onPrimary,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              navigation.navigateToPageClear(
                  path: NavigationConstants.LOGIN_VIEW);
              localeManager.deletedPref(PreferencesKeys.TOKEN);
              var token =
                  LocaleManager.instance.getStringValue(PreferencesKeys.TOKEN);
              inspect(token);
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.login_outlined,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: indexx == 0
                  ? CartView()
                  : indexx == 1
                      ? MarView()
                      : indexx == 2
                          ? const PomView()
                          : const SizedBox()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Hello, how can I do this? Do you have a source you can show as an example?

Comment: Have you seen riverpod.dev in the past two months?  It has a lot more material now.